# function to get position in two arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ejs

In javascript or EJS

Hi, I have the followings arrays

```
ID totales: 76,76,76,78,17,37,30,177,30,177,1,2,3,5,64,30,31,35,36,17,17,37,76,1,2,3,5,35,37,33,30,31,35,36,17,17,37,17,37,35,37,80,35,37,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5,81,76,30,31,35,36,17,1,2,3,5,81,0,76,64,61,21,22,18,24,19,26,35,37,17,37,17,37,17,37

Porcantes Totales: 70,70,100,100,70,70,85,60,100,100,66.7,100,100,50,100,70,80,70,50,90,90,40,100,66.7,100,100,50,70,90,60,30,90,60,50,60,80,40,60,60,40,60,11.1,80,80,66.7,100,100,50,66.7,100,100,50,66.7,100,100,50,0,100,40,60,40,50,70,66.7,100,100,50,100,60,0,0,50,70,70,100,70,80,60,80,80,20,50,50,70,60,50

ID propios: 30,177
```

I need to get the position in "ID totales" where are "ID propios" that is to say 30 and 177,

with the purpose of get the same position in "Porcantes Totales" and may to make a sum with the values in the position of 30 and position of 177, this by separate parts and store them in a variable

thanks

In javascript or EJS

the code is

```
result.forEach(function(results){ %>

                        <%long=(results.category_results.length)
                        for(i=0; i<long; i++){ %>

                            <%results.category_results[i].category_id%>
                            <%listRP.push(results.category_results[i].category_id)%>

                            <%listResPropio=listRP%>

                        <br><br><br>
                        <% } %>
                        <% }) %>

                        <%
                        listR=[]
                        listP=[]
                        allResult.forEach(function(allR){ %>

                        <%long=(allR.category_results.length)
                        for(i=0; i<long; i++){ %>

                            <%allR.category_results[i].category_id%>
                            <%listR.push(allR.category_results[i].category_id)%>
                            <%listP.push(allR.category_results[i].percentage)%>

                            <%listaResultados=listR%>
                            <%listaPorcentajes=listP%>

                        <% } %>
                        <% }) %> 


                        <%aaaa = []
                        var a
                        var b
                        %>

                        ID totales: <%=listaResultados%><br>
                        Porcantes Totales: <%=listaPorcentajes%><br>
                        ID propios: <%=listResPropio%><br>

                        <% for(i=0; i<listaResultados.length; i++){ %>
                        <% for(a=0; a<listResPropio.length; a++){ %>

                        <% if(listaResultados[i]==listResPropio[a]){  %>

                           <% a=listaResultados[i] %>

                        <%= a  %>

                        <% } %>

                        <% } %> 

                        <% } %>
```

Comment: what is to do with the values 30 and 177?

Comment: Let me be if I am correct. You want to get the position of those numbers in the first array, then find the value of that position in the second and return the sum of the numbers?

Comment: Has to be all the position that match the number or just the first one?

Comment: do you need the index positions of 30 and 117? And then use the index positions to sum up the corresponding "Porcantes Totales"?

Comment: Do i understand correct? You want to get the positions of two numbers (30,177)  in the array "ID totales"  And than sum the values from the array "Porcantes Totales" with the corrosponding index numbers. And finally store them in an object.

Comment: where do you get the position 177 from? the array have a length of 86.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work

```js
var ID_totales = [76,76,76,78,17,37,30,177,30,177,1,2,3,5,64,30,31,35,36,17,17,37,76,1,2,3,5,35,37,33,30,31,35,36,17,17,37,17,37,35,37,80,35,37,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5,81,76,30,31,35,36,17,1,2,3,5,81,0,76,64,61,21,22,18,24,19,26,35,37,17,37,17,37,17,37]

var Porcantes_Totales = [70,70,100,100,70,70,85,60,100,100,66.7,100,100,50,100,70,80,70,50,90,90,40,100,66.7,100,100,50,70,90,60,30,90,60,50,60,80,40,60,60,40,60,11.1,80,80,66.7,100,100,50,66.7,100,100,50,66.7,100,100,50,0,100,40,60,40,50,70,66.7,100,100,50,100,60,0,0,50,70,70,100,70,80,60,80,80,20,50,50,70,60,50]

function ID_propios(ID){
  
  return ID.map(a=>Porcantes_Totales[ID_totales.indexOf(a)]).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)   
}

console.log(
  ID_propios([30, 177])
)
```

Comment: I supposed they were meant to be an array and that is how the parameter is set. The function I created accepts an array of numbers

Comment: That was also what i understood. Also, your code is a state of art, with one line and does the trick. Very elegant way of handling.